# Etimología de "longuis" / Hacerse el longuis

Tags: etimología, historia, coloquialismos, españa, locuciones

En español hay un coloquialismo que es "hacerse el longuis", con el significado de "hacerse el distraído" o no querer darse por enterado.

> **[longuis](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NbdvlBR)** (también *longui*).
>
> hacerse el longui, o longuis
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Hacerse el distraído.
>
> Fuente: [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NbdvlBR)

Buscando el origen de tal expresión, me he encontrado con diferentes posibilidades. Hay quien afirma que es de reciente cuño:

> HACERSE EL LONGUIS [es una expresión ochentera]. En el 70 ya aparecía hacerse el longui y en el 84 entró también como longuis. Se usa para el que se hace el distraído o el sueco (que, según la RAE, viene de zueco, por cierto).
>
> Fuente: [sinfaltas.com](https://sinfaltas.com/2016/01/13/la-rae-mola/)

Por otro lado, [Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-surge-la-expresion-hacerse-el-longuis/) (que me parece un poco más fiable) indica:

> El término ‘longuis’ proviene de la palabra en latín ‘liongus’ cuyo significado es lejano/apartado y éste dio la palabra ‘longuiso’ para referirse a aquella persona cobarde que huía de una responsabilidad y que se escondía en algún lugar lejano y/o apartado para desentenderse de una obligación

El blog de elListoQueTodoLoSabe advierte que:

> Al contrario de lo que muchas personas piensan, esta expresión no ha surgido recientemente ni proviene de ninguna jerga de los más jóvenes.

He intentado verificar las afirmaciones de este blog sobre el origen de la expresión (buscando en alguno de los otros sitios habituales, como Etimologías de Chile) pero he tenido poca suerte.

Aunque me inclino por creer la entrada del listo que todo lo sabe (porque ha sido muy fiable en otras ocasiones, más que por el hecho de que se haga eco de esa "falsa" etimología que dice que la expresión es de reciente cuño), me parece que ambas afirmaciones andan en "empate técnico" y me gustaría poder encontrar algo que de verdad valide alguna de las dos (y desmienta la otra).

¿Alguien sabe cómo se formó la expresión "hacerse el longuis"? Alguno de los que os manejáis con soltura rebuscando en versiones antiguas del diccionario o documentos similares, ¿encontráis que esta expresión se usase ya hace mucho tiempo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos a repasar toda la información de la que disponemos. Empezando por el NTLLE, vemos que la primera aparición en el DLE es en 1970:

> **longui (hacerse el).** fr. fig. y fam. Hacerse el distraído.

Resulta interesante que muy cerca en el diccionario aparezca lo siguiente:

> **longuiso.** (Del lat. *longus*, apartado, lejano.) m. *Germ.* Hombre cobarde, longares.
>
> **longares.** (De *alongar*.) m. *Germ.* Hombre cobarde, longuiso.

Curioso caso de definiciones que se referencian la una a la otra, aunque da igual porque ambas palabras no aparecen ya en el DLE. Estas dos palabras bien podrían haber dado *longui* o *longuis*, sobre todo como apócope de *longuiso*, dado que una situación muy normal para *hacerse el longuis* es cuando no te atreves a salir voluntario para algo que te acobarda hacer. Así que de momento *el listo que todo lo sabe* parece que lleva las de ganar.

Busquemos en el CORDE a ver qué encontramos:

> *No se haga el longui, amigo.*
>
> Miguel Hernández, "Quién te ha visto y quién te ve y sombra de lo que eras. Auto sacramental", 1934 (España).

Y en la hemeroteca:

> *El timado se hizo el «longui», y, siguiendo al estafador, lo mandó detener apenas
>   halló á su paso el primer guardia.*
>
> El Imparcial (Madrid). 6/5/1910, página 3.

Nótese que vamos ya por 1910, y entonces se usaba la palabra entrecomillada, buen síntoma de que la palabra era, por entonces, de reciente cuño o no muy extendida. También se encuentran casos de personajes apodados "el Longui", como el del siguiente texto:

> *Era el tal* Longui *avisador del teatro, y para los que no estén avisados de lo
>   que es un avisador diré que es el* corre, ve y tráeme *de los artistas.
>
>   El que quiera enterarse de los secretos misteriosos de entre bastidores, feliz mortal que no sepa nada de esto, que convide al* Longui *y el* Longui *le introducirá en el escenario y le enterará así de lo que por allí ocurre.*
>
> Por esos mundos (Madrid). [1/12/1908, página 19.](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003157625&page=19&search=%22el%20longui%22&lang=es)

También hubo un torero hacia 1900, Manuel Casado, apodado "El Longuis". Y todavía encuentro un caso más antiguo:

> *Micaela se hacía la longui cuando se tocaba al asunto, y la muchacha no osaba desacatar las órdenes de la abuela, dura y sostenida para lo que no era de su gusto.*
>
> La Alhambra (Granada). [15/11/1901, página 4.](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004293662&page=4&search=longui&lang=es)

Y del mismo año:

> *El tío José se cansó en balde, pregunta va pregunta viene, y en vista de que «tos» se coscaban y hacían los* longuis *sin querer dar luz sobre la «custión», bajó al día siguiente á la ciudad y dio parte de lo «sucedió».*
>
> La Alhambra (Granada). [30/6/1901, página 6.](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004291972&page=6&search=longuis&lang=es)

Por lo menos de momento sabemos que la expresión tiene más de un siglo. Continuemos con el *Fichero general* de la RAE... y no hay suerte. Hay 22 fichas para el término *longui* pero ninguna da pista alguna sobre su origen. Y cómo no, el diccionario etimológico abreviado de Corominas no incluye la voz *longui*.

Acabándoseme las opciones, me dirijo al [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=longui&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clongui%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blongui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLongui%3B%2Cc0), pero según el diagrama la expresión surgió a partir de 1900, siendo los casos anteriores correspondientes a otros usos de la palabra.

Resumiendo: el uso de la palabra aparece alrededor de 1900, y todo parece indicar que sea una forma apocopada de *longuiso*, "hombre cobarde". El ejemplo de Micaela de 1901 parece confirmarlo ya que habla de una muchacha que se hacía "la longui" por no atreverse a desacatar las órdenes de su abuela.

Curiosamente, encuentro algunos casos de la misma época, pero no tengo claro si se usan de la misma manera, porque aparece como interjección en una revista militar ("La Nación militar"). Los dejo aquí:

> - *Longuis, se ha creído toda mi charla: si supiera él que es producto
>     de la uña... ¡me mataba!* (1909)
> - *—Lo adivinaba, que me lleve cinco pelas pa entre los dos disfrutarlas; en fin que toos esos líos eran porque deseabas una juerguecita, ¡longuis! pus dilo asi sin...* (1904)

Se [podría argumentar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48522783#48522783) que igual se usa como sinónimo de "tonto", y encajaría con el uso actual de "hacerse el longui" como "hacerse el tonto":

> Tonto, se ha creído toda mi charla...

Lo que nos lleva al siguiente texto, el más antiguo que encuentro y a la vez el que más me desconcierta:

> ¿Que qué es ser *vivo*? ¡Ay que gracia!
>   Pues nada; no ser un *méndigo*
>   y tener *pupila* y *taçto*,
>   educación, *lao* izquierdo,
>   *labia* para las mujeres
>   y *coba* para to el género
>   humano, *ú* lo que es lo mismo,
>   ser un *longuis* distinguiendo
>   y no ser un *primo*, más
>   que cuando convenga serlo [...].
>
> La Nación militar. [13/8/1899, n.º 33, página 6.](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003268169&page=6&search=longuis&lang=es)

No entiendo a qué se refiere cuando dice que "ser vivo" es "ser un longuis distinguiendo". Puede que sea simplemente que hay que distinguir cuándo hay que hacerse el tonto y cuándo no.

Tampoco tengo claro si la palabra se usa con el mismo significado en un texto que habla sobre personas que remitieron a un diario las soluciones exactas de unos pasatiempos publicados el día anterior. La mayoría firman con seudónimos:

> Han remitido soluciones exactas:
>   *A la charada:* Julia Mango y Mata, [...]. Un galerino en el polo, Los de Belchite y el Charco, Un aciertacharadístico, Higinio Estébanez, Mariano Martínez, Dos
>   longuis, Anacleto Llama, [...].
>
> El Heraldo de Madrid. [18/2/1894, página 3.](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000414998&page=3&search=longuis&lang=es)

Este es el caso más antiguo que he encontrado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 3):

Es posible que venga del caló:

> ### 5.172 longui o longuis: hacerse el ~
>
> Comenta Sanmartín Sáez (1998a) que la voz podría tener su origen en la voz caló *longui* ‘inocente’, documentada solamente en el diccionario de Llorens, o, contrariamente, podría haber sido influída por la frase *ser muy largo* ‘ser avispado’. La tercera posibilidad, que negaría también el origen gitano de la voz, se atestigua en el diccionario de Terreros y Pando:
>
> > “Fr. *Longui*. Lat. *Linteum*, voz de relaciones, cierto paño ó lienzo, que sirve en los baños en Turquía” (NTLLE: 1787 Terreros y Pando (G-O)).
>
> En la 22ª edición del DRAE, de 2001, se recogen ambas variantes de la voz *longui* igual que *longuis*, y las frases se definen como ‘hacerse el distraído’ y llevan la marca de uso coloquial. Desafortunadamente, no se informa al lector sobre la etimología de la voz en cuestión.
>
> Se atestigua *longui* como parte de frase *hacerse el longui* ‘hacerse el distraído’ a partir de la 19ª edición en 1970 y llevaba las marcas de uso familiar y figurado. Su variante formal *longuis* se registra desde la 21ª edición, de 1992, bajo la misma entrada.
>
> Ambas variantes vienen también en el DEA, pero con una diferencia en el tratamiento: la variante *longuis* fi gura en el primer lugar, i.e. se marca como más frecuente, lo que más tarde hemos comprobado encórpora académicos. La locución ostenta la marca de uso coloquial e idéntico es también el texto de la definición: ‘Hacerse el distraído’.
>
> Hemos constatado que la variante *hacerse el longuis* es más frecuente que *hacerse el longui.* Curiosamente, en ningún repertorio lexicográfico se nos informa sobre el carácter invariable de *longuis*. Hemos encontrado en CORDE un curioso ejemplo en femenino *hacerse la longuis* y no hemos resistido la tentación de incluirlo también.
>
> > Todo el mundo se hace el «longui» por aquello de que no daba pelas en la SER.
> >     (CREA: 2009-06-18 [Díaz *La radio*])
>
> > —No te hagas el «longuis». La bragueta.
> >     (CREA: 2009-06-18 [Marsé *Rabos*])
>
> > —¡Qué me va a decir, idiota, que eres idiota! Pues ahí está mi reconcomio, que siempre que lo nombra es pa decir que es un gili, un palomino atontao, y yo me hago la «longuis» porque no es tiempo aún pa empezar la labor del casorio, que ya vendrá cuando tenga que venir. Ahora, a quien hay que trabajar es a la madre, y con la Raimunda estoy haciendo encaje de bolillos. Tú déjame a mí, que soy buena encajera.
> >     (CORDE: 2009-06-18 [DCañabate *Paseíllo*])
>
> - [*El léxico gitano en la lexicografía española*](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/124078/SpisyFF_389-2010-1_8.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

En estos dos artículos: [El Latín y el Humor en la Lengua Coloquial](https://minerva.usc.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10347/3550/pg_399-404_verba5.pdf?sequence=1) de Enrique Montero, y [Neologismos fraseológicos como palabras diacríticas en las locuciones en español](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/paremia/pdf/021/005_aguilar.pdf) de Manuel Agular, se sugiere que *longuis* surge como un juego humorístico de imitación de palabras de apariencia culta, agregando para ello una desinencia latina. Según el primero, vendría de "dar largas" o "pasar de largo".

Sería lo mismo que ha ocurrido (según esos investigadores) con otras palabras que terminan en -is, como *pompis* o *mutis*, y con otras terminaciones aparentemente latinas, como *tetamen* y *de chipendi*.

Answer (score 0):

Una expresión que nace en el Madrid de la década de 1920. Como es sabido, Longhi, significa «hacerse el despistado».

Todo parece indicar que la expresión se relaciona con el famoso historiador del Arte italiano Roberto Longhi, autor de obras importantísimas en el estudio de la pintura italiana.

En 1924, tras contraer matrimonio con Anna Banti, Roberto Longhi llegó a Madrid en su viaje de novios. Durante este viaje aprovechó su estancia para conocer otros estudiosos y fortalecer los lazos entre las universidades de ambos países, programando diferentes exposiciones que no pudieron llevarse a cabo por el recrudecimiento de la crisis económica.

Parece ser que Longhi, de familia humilde y por aquel entonces sólo un profesor más de la universidad, había invertido casi todos sus ahorros en el viaje, por lo que trató de economizar al máximo los gastos en el alojamiento y en comida. Tanto es así que los profesores con los que se reunía empezaron a sospechar que detrás de sus constantes invitaciones para organizar comidas y preparar proyectos no eran sino una excusa para comer o cenar gratis.

Puntualmente, cuando llegaba la cuenta, Longhi sacaba su cuaderno de apuntes y se ponía a escribir todas las cosas de las que se había hablado durante la comida, pidiendo que no le molestasen por temor a olvidarse algo. Los profesores españoles notaron enseguida este «truco» de Longhi, pero movidos por la simpatía y la ternura que les inspiraba el italiano, decidieron no decirle nada y ayudarle en su momento de dificultad económica.

Esta simpatía no fue en cambio óbice para que la anécdota se propagara rápidamente entre los estudiantes madrileños, que empezaron a utilizar «**hacerse el longui**» (Longhi se pronuncia exactamente «longui») **para referirse a quien se hace el despistado**.